# Setting a model parameter whenever it is updated ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

new to rails here. I have an RoR app, which has a model called pieces. The pieces have an integer parameter called status. Whenever a piece is created or updated, I want the piece.status to be set to 2 if the devise current_user.id method is not equal to 1. This works for my create method, but when I put a similar line into my update method, nothing happens. What should I do?

Here is my controller

```
class PiecesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_piece, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  respond_to :html

def index
    @pieces = Piece.all
    respond_with(@pieces)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@piece)
  end

  def new
    @piece = current_user.pieces.build
    respond_with(@piece)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @piece = current_user.pieces.build(piece_params)
    @piece.status = 2 if current_user.id != 1
    flash[:notice] = 'Piece was successfully created.' if @piece.save
    respond_with(@piece)
  end

  def update
    flash[:notice] = 'Piece was successfully updated.' if @piece.update(piece_params)
    respond_with(@piece)
  end

  def destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'Piece was successfully deleted.' if @piece.destroy
    respond_with(@piece)
  end

  private
    def set_piece
      @piece = Piece.find(params[:id])
    end

    def piece_params
      params.require(:piece).permit(:title, :image, :genre, :size, :price,   :description, :status)
    end
end
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PiecesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @piece.attributes = piece_params
    @piece.status = 2 if current_user.id != 1
    if @piece.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Piece was successfully updated.'
      respond_with(@piece)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, Jagdeep. I forgot to mention that I only wanted to set this action if the devise current_user.id != 1. I tried this, saying    self.status = 2 if current_user.id != 1, got an error

Comment: you won't find `current_user` in the model. So, above wont work.

Comment: Exactly. So how can I implement this? In the controller? This works for my create method, but I need it to work for my update method as well.

Comment: Few suggestions: you can skip the irrelevant code in the question like `index`, `new`, `show`, `edit`, and `destroy`

Comment: Also, to set something in DB based on `current_user`'s id is not a great way. You should use some other attribute from `current_user` which will never change e.g. `email`. Because ids may differ.

Comment: And I will change the id to email as well

Comment: Jagdeep, this code was working, but today I got a missing template error whenever I update my pieces. What is going on? I edited my question so you can see the method

Comment: Got it working, I thought you would be interested. I added validations to my pieces fields, and so to fix this I added `else` and  `reder :edit`

Comment: Cool. Way to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
def update
  @piece = current_user.pieces.find(params[:id])
  @piece.status = 2 if current_user.id != 1
  if @piece.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Piece was successfully updated.'
    respond_with(@piece)
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a migration file to add payload field in peices.

```
class AddPayloadToPeices < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :peices, :payload, :jsonb
    end
end
```

2. Now set payload in your Controller's action :

```
peice.payload = { current_user_id: current_user.id }
```

3. Now in Peice Model :

```
before_save :set_status, if: 'payload[:current_user_id] && payload[:current_user_id] != 1'

def set_status
    status = 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more about Callbacks: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

You can define methods before and after save or update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. @Jagdeep Singh 's answer helped a lot, and was working until I added validations for the fields of my pieces. Whenever these fields did not meet their validations in the update action, I would get a no template error. So, the best way to do this is the following:

```
def update
  @piece.attributes = piece_params
  @piece.status = 2 if current_user.id != 1
  if @piece.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Piece was successfully updated.'
    respond_with(@piece)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```